# Ajax call not working before login in form authentication

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-ajax

I am using cookie based form authentication in my application and login in my application through jquery ajax call.when i apply Authorization tag in my web.config.my ajax function stop calling login action method in controller. The issue is that before login form is not authenticated and ajax call fail to call server action method.how can i enable ajax call before login. here is my web.config code.if i remove "authorization" tag from my web.config code works fine.

```
  <authorization>
  <deny users="?"/>
</authorization>
```

Comment: Show us Ajax call code and controller action, seems its failing in model binding... as you say you have applied AllowAnonymous.

Answer (score 1):

You will need to turn off authentication on your login action (ie AllowAnonymous):

```
   [AllowAnonymous]
    public ActionResult Login(string returnUrl)
    {
        ViewBag.ReturnUrl = returnUrl;
        return View();
    }
```

Comment: i already try this but still ajax call not calling login method.